# Passar interface para SignalR Hub

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

Existe alguma maneira de passar uma interface como parâmetro no construtor do hub? Para algumas operações, precisava de aceder no hub a métodos da layer de repositórios através de interfaces. Existe alguma maneira de conseguir isto? Obrigado.